# TFSService and multiple cloud services - can't unlink

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 cloud services, live and staging, and I couldn't get staging to deploy from a TFSService build correctly - it kept either not deploying or deploying to live. The live cloud service is the one I originally created some time ago. I've deleted all builds for both services.

So I've tried to unlink both services in an attempt to relink just the staging one. Problem is that I can't unlink the live cloud service via the Azure portal. I get "Unlink TFS failed to complete cleanly. All info was removed from the Portal, but some might remain on TFS Hosted Services".

I've disassociated my TFS Service in my visualstudio.com admin area but I still get the error.

Can anyone advise what I can try next please?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about which error you are trying to get rid of?

Comment: I ha the same type of problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359824/failed-to-retrieve-deployment-history-when-i-try-to-view-the-deployment-tab-of-a