# Failed to retrieve deployment history when I try to view the deployment tab of a web site connected to TFS

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-roles

When I try to view the deployment tab of a web site connected to TFS, I get the following error:

Get/Refresh TFS OAuth token failed with invalid_grant

It used to work.  Doesn't work anymore.

And not able to disconnect this could service from TFS:
"Unlink TFS failed to complete cleanly. All info was removed from the Portal, but some might remain on TFS Hosted Services."

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this out? I am trying to disconnect from TFS and getting this error...

Comment: No, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I was able to use the link to connect to my Visual Studio Account.

It works now.